# Why does cons function called explicity works over Int in Scala?

Tags: scala, cons

You can create a new List in Scala using:

```
1 :: 2 :: Nil
```

In my understanding this can rewritten to:

```
Nil.::(2.::(1))
```

Mainly because :: fixty but if I write:

```
Nil :: 1 :: 2
```

I get "value :: is not a member of Int" what is totally expected because in scaladoc Int does not have ::, but I can't understand why if I translate that to:

```
1.::(2.::(Nil))
```

It works getting as output:

```
List(1.0, 2.0)
```

It looks like scalac auto casts the `1` and `2` to a type different than Int. Is that correct? If it is, why does it happen and which is this strange type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is funny.

Your expression

```
1.::(2.::(Nil))
```

is being parsed by the compiler as

```
1. :: (2. :: (Nil))
```

which, since `::` is right-associative, is the same as

```
1. :: 2. :: Nil
```

which, since `1.` is a valid way of writing a `Double`, is the same as

```
1.0 :: 2.0 :: Nil
```

which is a legal expression for constructing the `List[Double]`

```
List(1.0, 2.0)
```

Comment: So this is a bug of scala 2.9.2? Or this is how it is intended to work?

Comment: It's not a bug.  It's perfectly valid expresion.  It just looks a little funny when you leave out the spaces.

Comment: Why "1. :: (2. :: (Nil))" is parsed to "1.0 :: 2.0 :: Nil"? I though that operators ending in : have backward fixity.

Comment: Because in `1.` is being parsed as the `Double` `1.0`.  In other words, the dot is being interpreted as a mathematical decimal point, not as a dot separating an object from its method.

Comment: That's true "1.0.::(2.0.::(Nil))" return error, "1..::(Nil)" either. The answer then is that in scala you don't have to write 1.0, 1. is enough. In my opinion this is a little strange.

Comment: @rsan C++, python and a huge amount of mainstream languages treat `1.` as `1.0`, so it is quite expected behavior.

Comment: `1.` is deprecated in 2.10 and will be deleted in 2.11.

Comment: @rsan Scala followed Java convention for pretty much all literals, the sole exception being the additional multi-line strings. `1.` and `.1` are both valid `double` literals in Java, and, therefore, so they are in Scala. I think it is amazing that `1.` (and `01` as octal) is being deprecated in Scala, instead of following Java's path of adding even more variations to how one can write numeric literals. By the way, out of curiosity, what is your previous language background?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral I have written code in almost all the most used languages (C,C++,C#,Java, etc), it was more ignorance than anything else. IMHO, its just ok if this is deprecated,this can be confusing and writing the zero after the point doesn't hurt anyone. Something I like about all this "new" languages is that at some point they try to make more readable and less cryptic the syntaxis.

Answer (score 0):

You write that the expression

```
1 :: 2 :: Nil
```

can be rewritten as

```
Nil.::(2.::(1))
```

This is not quite correct, because `2.` is parsed as a `Double`. This could be fixed by adding parenthesis around 2, but then the compiler still complains as class `Int` does not support method `::`!

The given expression can be written as

```
(Nil.::(2)).::(1)
```

The other expression which you have is

```
1.::(2.::(Nil))
```

Here, the compiler parses `1.` and `2.` as doubles, i.e. it eagerly consumes as many characters as possible when reading a token. If you want to avoid that, then you either can put parenthesis around the integers or add a blank between the number and the dot:

```
1 .::(2 .::(Nil))
(1).::((2).::(Nil))
```

However, you get an error on these expressions too as `::` is not a member of class `Int` (nor a member of any class to which an implicit conversion exists).